# PyCharm prints letters in the editor instead of numbers

Tags: python, pycharm

When I try to type numbers into the editor of pycharm, I get this: (numbers from 0-9):

[image: picture]

Any ideas about how to fix this? I have the right keyboard layout, and I have no plugins trigger this.
This happens only in pycharm(0123456789)

Comment: Possibly a stupid question (you could not have typed this question), but still: does this happen in any other program?

Comment: When you press numbers 0-9 you get that output :/ ? What encoding are you using ? What fonts ?

Comment: I used UTF-8 and the standart font "monospaced" (now fixed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should configure Pycharm's console font to make it display as you wish. Go to `File->Settings->Editor->Font` and add the font you want.
[image]

Comment: ok this worked. For some fonts (like the standart) didtn work. So thx

Comment: If it worked, please consider of accepting the answer so the question can be closed and others having this issue can find the answer easily.